# Variable assignment and modification (in python)

Tags: python, list, variables

When I ran this script (Python v2.6):

```
a = [1,2]
b = a
a.append(3)
print a
>>>> [1,2,3]
print b
>>>> [1,2,3]
```

I expected `print b` to output `[1,2]`. Why did b get changed when all I did was change a? Is b permanently tied to a? If so, can I make them independent? How?

Comment: @Felix I'd say not quite a dup - he isn't asking only how to clone but rather why Python behaves a certain way.

Comment: "[Python has names](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/presentation.html#python-has-names)" is very good part of even better tutorial/introduction regarding this behavior.

Comment: @thegrinner: Yeah, I was a bit too quick. Just hinting at it would have been better.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Memory management in Python involves a private heap memory location containing all Python objects and data structures.

Python's runtime only deals in references to objects (which all live in the heap): what goes on Python's stack are always references to values that live elsewhere.

```
>>> a = [1, 2]
```

[image: python variables]

```
>>> b = a
```

[image: python variables]

```
>>> a.append(3)
```

[image: python variables]

Here we can clearly see that the variable `b` is bound to the same object as `a`.

You can use the `is` operator to tests if two objects are physically the same, that means if they have the same address in memory. This can also be tested also using the [`id()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#id) function.

```
>>> a is b
>>> True
>>> id(a) == id(b)
>>> True
```

So, in this case, **you must explicitly ask for a copy**.
Once you've done that, there will be no more connection between the two distinct list objects.

```
>>> b = list(a)
>>> a is b
>>> False
```

[image: python variables]

Answer (score 13):

Objects in Python are stored by reference—you aren't assigning the value of `a` to `b`, but a pointer to the object that `a` is pointing to.

To emulate assignation by value, you can make a copy like so:

```
import copy

b = copy.copy(a)

# now the code works as "expected"
```

Be aware this has performance disadvantages.

In the case of an array, there's a special method that relies on slices:

```
b = a[:]

# code also works as expected here
```

---

*Update*– In addition to this, with some objects you can use the constructor—this includes lists:

```
b = list(a)
```

Comment: DiggyF pointed this out in a comment below - you'll want to replace `b = a[:]` with `b = list(a)` for both readability reasons and for anything that works with numpy.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer - Pointers.

When you type `b = a` it is setting `b` to look at the same array that `a` looks at.  You have to make a new array with copies of the elements to separate them.  In this case, something like `b = [n for n in a]` would work fine.  For more complex operations you may want to check out http://docs.python.org/library/copy.html.

Comment: Also `b = a[:]` works, and it's more "pythonic" (or so they say)

Answer (score 4):

You might want to look at [this](http://henry.precheur.org/python/copy_list) link. The problem you have here is `a` and `b` both point to the same memory location, so changing one changes the other. Instead, you want to do something like this:

```
a = [1,2]
b = list(a)
```

Comment: From the article in the link: "Next time you see a [:] try to replace it with list, your code should be more readable. Do it, the devil is in the details.". So it is advisable to use `b=list(a)`. This is also a good idea because when people switch from a list to a numpy array, then a[:] will be reference to the same data.

Answer (score 3):

`a` is a pointer to the list `[1,2]`.

When you do the assignment `b = a` the value of b is the address of the list `[1,2]`.

So when you do `a.append(3)` you are not actually changing `a`, you are changing the list that `a` points to. Since `a` and `b` both point to the same list, they both appear to change when you modify the other.

Answer (score 3):

If you simply want to copy the contents of list a to b, instead of making b a pointer to a:

```
b = a[:]
```

Using the slice operator will copy the contents of the list into b such that you example would become:

```
a = [1,2]
b = a[:]
a.append(3)
print a
>>>> [1,2,3]
print b
>>>> [1,2]
```