# Trying to duplicate a list and modify one version of it in Python 2

Tags: python, list, variables, indexing, python-2.x

I want to duplicate a list and modify the duplicate, but when I try this, I end up modifying the original as well.

A highly simplified version of my problem:

```
list = [2,3,6,8,9,6,7,4,56,8,9,6,7,8]

new_list = list

new_list[2] = 'n'

print list
print new_list
```

I only want to change item 2 of the new list, but when I try this, both the new list and the old list change to:

```
[2,3,'n',8,9,6,7,4,56,8,9,6,7,8]
```

Is there something quite fundamental I'm missing here?

I can make it do what I want if I add each item of the list to the next list one by one:

```
list = [2,3,6,8,9,6,7,4,56,8,9,6,7,8]

new_list = []

for item in list:
    new_list.append(item)

new_list[2] = 'n'

print list
print new_list
```

If I do that, only the `new_list` changes, but is there a more straight-forward way?

Comment: Possibile duplicate of [Variable assignment and modification (in python)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6793872/variable-assignment-and-modification-in-python) and [How to clone a list in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-a-list-in-python)

Comment: i think cloning was the answer, though not really my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make a new copy of your list, try:

```
newList = list(oldList)
```

Or more <strike>cryptic</strike> concise via slicing:

```
newlist = oldList[:]
```

Just *assigning* `oldList` to `newList` will result in two names pointing to the same object, like so:

[image: http://henry.precheur.org/python/copy_list]

Generic object copying functions are provided by the [copy module](http://docs.python.org/library/copy.html). (Image taken from: http://henry.precheur.org/python/copy_list).

Answer (score 1):

Use `new_list = a_list[:]` to make a shallow copy of `a_list`:

```
a_list = [2,3,6,8,9,6,7,4,56,8,9,6,7,8]    
new_list = a_list[:]    
new_list[2] = 'n'    
print a_list
print new_list
```

yields

```
[2, 3, [6, 8], 9, 6, 7, 4, 56, 8, 9, 6, 7, 8]
[2, 3, [6, 'n'], 9, 6, 7, 4, 56, 8, 9, 6, 7, 8]
```

Think of variable names as references which point at objects.
When you say `new_list = a_list` you are telling Python to make `new_list` point to the same object that `a_list` points at. This is why modifying `new_list` also modified `a_list`.

---

PS. Resist the temptation to name a list `list`. This overrides the builtin definition for the `list` function.

PPS. `new_list = a_list[:]` creates a shallow copy. If

```
a_list = [1, 2,[3,6]]
new_list = a_list[:]
```

then

```
new_list[2][1] = 'n'
```

would modify the sublist in both `a_list` and `new_list`. If you want do a deep copy then use

```
import copy
new_list = copy.deepcopy(a_list)
```

instead.

Comment: well, yes, in my actual script the variable is called "AGP"

Comment: and thanks for the tip about sub-lists, i was just about to be caught by that

Comment: "Resist the temptation to all a list list."?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are missing something fundamental. Python will never make a copy of a object, unless you explicitly ask for it, as in `myList[:]`.

Whenever you use `=`, as in `mylist = [2,3,4]`, you assign the *name* on the left to the *value* on the right. In this case you have a value, `[2,3,4]` (a literal) and you give a new name to this particular list, `"mylist"`.

The same happens when you write `new_list = mylist`: On the right hand side is a *value*, but this time it's given by its name. Python looks this name up and finds the existing list. Then this list gets a new name, `"newlist"`, but you still have only one list (with two names for it).

Comment: This is misleading.  You need to recognize that when you assign numbers or, confusingly, strings or tuples, changing one will not change the other.

Answer (score 0):

When you're doing

```
new_list = list
```

your `new_list` isn't actually a new list, it's a new reference to the old list.

You can create a copy with slice notation:

```
>>> l = [1, 2]
>>> l2 = l[:]
>>> l2[0]=42
>>> l
[1, 2]
>>> l2
[42, 2]
```

And also, don't use `list` as a variable name, it conflicts with builtin `list` type.