# unexpected behaviour with variables definition in python

Tags: python, numpy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Variable assignment and modification (in python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6793872/variable-assignment-and-modification-in-python)

I just noticed that variable assignation in python had some behaviour which I didn't expect. For example:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.zeros([1, 3])
B = A

for ind in range(A.shape[1]):
    A[:, ind] = ind
    B[:, ind] = 2 * ind
print 'A = ', A
print 'B = ', B
```

outputs

A =  [[ 0.  2.  4.]]

B =  [[ 0.  2.  4.]]

While I was expecting:

A = [[ 0.  1.  2.]]

B = [[ 0.  2.  4.]]

If I replace "B = A" by "B = np.zeros([1, 3])", then I have the right thing.
I can't reproduce the unexpected result in Ipython terminal. I got that result in SciTE 3.1.0 using F5 key to run the code. I'm using Python(x, y) 2.7.2.3 distro in Win7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, `B` is just another name for `A`, so when you change one you change the other. This is a common "problem" with mutable objects in Python. With numpy arrays, you can use the `copy()` function.

However, this also happens with mutable containers, such as lists or dictionaries. To avoid this, you can one of one of these: (depending on the complexity of the mutable)

```
B = A[:]  #makes a copy of only the first level of the mutable
B = copy(A)  #same as above, returns a 'shallow copy' of A
B = deepcopy(A)  #copies every element in the mutable, on every level
```

Note that to use the `copy` and `deepcopy` functions, you need to import them from the standard module `copy`.

See also: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2612802/1907098)

Comment: Alright, why can't I reproduce it in Ipython terminal?

Comment: As in you don't need to make a copy? I'm not entirely sure - someone tag in here?

Comment: @user1850133: It should behave exactly the same in the IPython terminal.  Perhaps if you show a transcript from the IPython session, we'll be able to see what's happening.

Comment: @Volatility: "copy and deepcopy methods" -> "copy and deepcopy functions"

Comment: @MarkDickinson yeah, sorry, fixed it up

Comment: It does actually give the same result in Ipython terminal. In fact earlier I did the following, which I though was equivalent to the code in the OP. 
In [1]: import numpy as np

[...]

In [13]: A = np.zeros([1, 3])

In [14]: B = A

In [15]: A
Out[15]: array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.]])

In [16]: B
Out[16]: array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.]])

In [17]: B = np.ones([1, 3])

In [18]: B
Out[18]: array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.]])

In [19]: A
Out[19]: array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.]])

Comment: "is pointing to" -> "is a name for".

Answer (score 2):

```
B = A
```

makes `A` and `B` point to the same object. That's why they will be changed simultaneously.

Use

```
B = A.copy()
```

and it will work as awaited.