# Why does changing a Python list created by assigning another modify both?

Tags: python

Can someone explain to me what *the hell* is going on here:

```
>>> listOne=[1,2,3,4]
>>> listOne
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> listTwo=listOne
>>> listTwo
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> listTwo[0]=0
>>> listTwo
[0, 2, 3, 4]
>>> listOne
[0, 2, 3, 4]
```

I've been quite clear I only want to change the first element of the list `listTwo`, but clearly `listOne` has remained linked to it and is edited also. There is nothing in the documentation about the equals operator that I can find that explains this...

I can of course fix it by turning `listOne` into a tuple after the assignment to `listTwo`.

Comment: May I recommend [The Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/)? As to your specific question, see https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html

Comment: `listTwo=listOne`: you have copied the reference: they both point to the same object.

Comment: The answer to this question explains it nicely: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6793872/variable-assignment-and-modification-in-python

Comment: Very good - thanks all, that is clear

Comment: BTW -- in the future, try to choose titles that make it clear what your question is, not just what data structure or operator that question revolves around.