# How to modify the sequence(not range) in the for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I just want to get a prime number list, but I find that the for loops more times than I image, it seems that the sequence don't change even though I modified the variable with the same name.

I try name nums as global, but nothing changed.

```py
nums = list(range(2, 11))
count = 0
for num in nums:
    nums = list(filter(lambda a: a == num or a % num, nums))
    count += 1
print(count)  # 9
print(nums)
```

I want `nums = list...` can modify **nums** in `for num in nums`, and the count is 4.
Thank you.

Comment: Closely related: [Reassigning value of iterator while iterating through it](//stackoverflow.com/a/53116048)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without understanding exactly why you want to do what you want to do and whether it is necessary or avoidable, here is a solution that might do what you want:

```
nums = list(range(2, 11))
count = 0
for num in nums:
    new_nums = list(filter(lambda a: a == num or a % num, nums))
    del nums[:]
    nums.extend(new_nums)
    count += 1
print(count)  # 4
print(nums)
```

Your original implementation was creating *a new variable* called with the old name `nums`. However, it was a new variable/memory object of which the loop was not aware. The proposed solution keeps the original object and modifies it by first deleting all existing elements and then adding all new elements of the list.

Comment: Thanks, I wanna know why use `nums.extend()` can change nums' value in for loop, but `=` can't. Is variable left at `=` a new variable, but `nums.extend()` is the old value? Sorry for my poor English⊙﹏⊙

Comment: @heppen A simplified explanation. When the loop starts, it will use whatever list was specified at the beginning. That list is an "object". You need to modify _that_ object and the loop will be "aware" of those changes. However, you were creating a new list object and simply naming as `nums` does not modify the _original_ object. The following may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6793872/8033585. Also, try the following exercise: `a=[1,2]; b=a; a=[1,2]; a.append(3); print(a); print(b)`.

Comment: @heppen Finally learn about `is` and `id()` in Python, i.e., https://stackoverflow.com/q/13650293/8033585 and try adding `print(id(nums))` after each `nums = ...` in your original code.

Answer (score 0):

Does this solve your problem?

```
nums = list(range(2, 11))

def f(num, nums):
    return list(filter(lambda a: a == num or a % num, nums))

count = 0
for i in range(len(nums)):
    if i < len(nums):
        nums = f(nums[i], nums)
        count+=1
print(nums)
print(count)
```

[2,3,5,7]

4

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I think your code just use `if` to reduce `count` value, but the `for` still repeat 9 times. What I want is  to reduce `for` loop times.