# Why am I getting a IndexError: list index out of range error in the code below?

Tags: python, function, debugging

I just want to remove the duplicates of the word passed but it's not working.

```
wordlist = ["a", "a", 'b', "b", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
new_list = wordlist
word = "a"

for i in range(len(wordlist)):
    if wordlist[i] == word:
        new_list.remove(word)

print(new_list)
```

Comment: new_list and wordlist are the same object in your case. id(new_list)  equals with id(wordlist). Pay attention on mutability in python.

Comment: If the order doesn't matter the easiest way is `new_list = list(set(wordlist))`

Answer (score 1):

Because `new_list` and `wordlist` point to the same object. You should use `new_list = wordlist.copy()` to create the copy of the list.

```
wordlist = ["a", "a", 'b', "b", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
new_list = wordlist.copy()
word = "a"

for i in range(len(wordlist)):
    if wordlist[i] == word:
        new_list.remove(word)

print(new_list)
```

Note: It is not advisable to modify the containers while iterating over the same.

Answer (score 1):

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6793872/variable-assignment-and-modification-in-python) explained well.

In order to make it work, you have to explicitly ask for a copy.

```
wordlist = ["a", "a", 'b', "b", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
new_list = list(wordlist)

word = "a"

for i in range(len(wordlist)):
    if wordlist[i] == word:
        new_list.remove(word)

print(new_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Either make `new_list` a true shallow copy:

```
new_list = wordlist[:]
```

Otherwise, `new_list` is just another reference to the same list object and your initially created range reaches indeces that no longer exist after a couple of removals.

Or (better) build it from scratch:

```
new_list = [w for w in word_list if w != word]
```